# Should I use Pages or DataObjects for large amount of entries?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm wondering what is the best approach or best practice in this situation:

- I have few categories of data (let's say: news, events, advertisements,
  gear)
- The number of records will range from a few dozen, up to a couple of thousand
- I will need one common view for all of those categories and also separate ones for each

At the beginning, I was thinking that I will create a base page and I'm going to use a holder-page pattern, but now I have some doubts. Isn't it better to use DataObjects and simply use Pages to manage them?

What is your experience with using holder-page pattern for thousands of pages? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you to decide. Pages are also DataObjects and you can manage them just like you do with other DataObjects. Eg. use a GridField, ModelAdmin or other means such as [Lumberjack](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-lumberjack).

The SiteTree can also handle large amount of pages, so it's not really an issue in that regard.

I think you'd have to answer this purely from an architectural point of view:

- Do my data-objects have an URL?
- Do my data-objects need to be versioned?
- Do I need a hierarchy of objects (parent- and child-pages)?
- Are my objects being displayed as individual pages, so that they also need metadata, such as meta-title, description, opengraph-tags etc.?
- Should my objects show up in the xml sitemap?

If you answer most of these questions with *yes*, then using Pages is probably the better approach as it'll limit the number of things you'd have to implement yourself.